# Why does deleting these two lines lead to ld error "undefined reference"?

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, ld

I have a project using opencv and cmake which builds 100% fine.

Then, I go to a C++ source file, which contains these lines, among other nonremarkable lines:

```
cv::imshow("Test", display);
cv::waitKey(0);
```

And I delete ONLY these two lines. Try building again, and I get:

```
$ make
(...)
[ 77%] Linking CXX executable project_test
libproject.so: undefined reference to `cv::resize(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::Size_<int>, double, double, int)'
libproject.so: undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'
libproject.so: undefined reference to `cv::cvtColor(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/project_test.dir/build.make:226: recipe for target 'project_test' failed
make[2]: *** [project_test] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:105: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/project_test.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/project_test.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:94: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Do you know of anything that would cause linking to fail on a small code deletion like that?

I tried building the original code from scratch and it worked, and I tried building the code with the two line deletion from scratch and it failed in the above way again.

---

**EDIT:**

Originally, the project's main CMakeLists.txt file contained this:

```
target_link_libraries(project opencv_core opencv_highgui)
```

Now I edited it to this:

```
target_link_libraries(project opencv_core opencv_imgproc opencv_highgui opencv_imgcodecs)
```

And the project builds again. But why did it build in the first place without those libraries explicitly being linked? **And why do those two lines work around that?**

Comment: Can you try compiling without `make`? Just use `g++`.

Comment: The build procedure is faulty. Those two lines cause the linker to load symbols that are needed in libproject.so. You need to find where those symbols are defined and add those libraries to the project specifically.

Comment: most likely that's not the cause. removing the two lines just triggered a "rebuild" and boom you're seeing the error. so if you want to really pinpoint the true cause, clean everything and build.

Comment: @codekaizer: I did, see "I tried building the original code from scratch and it worked, and I tried building the code with the two line deletion from scratch and it failed in the above way again." Sorry for it being unclear.